# component within component in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I have two independent components,defined one within the other in HTML. But my second(inner) component does not populate using the template mentioned in the templateUrl property of the inner component.

```js
//first component
angular.module('app').component('toolCtrl', {
  templateUrl: '/NFRManagementTools/static/js/templates/toolCtrl.html',
  controller: ToolCtrl,
  controllerAs: 'vtc',
});

//second coponent

angular.module('app').component('itemsView', {
  templateURL: '/NFRManagementTools/static/js/templates/itemsView.html',
  controller: ItemsViewCtrl

});
```

```html
<tool-ctrl>
  <items-view></items-view>
<tool-ctrl>
```

Comment: You don’t see the html for <items-view>? Like it’s not there?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for `transclude` option, in your parent component controller add the following option

```
angular.module('app').component('toolCtrl', {
  transclude: true,
  templateUrl: '/NFRManagementTools/static/js/templates/toolCtrl.html',
  controller: ToolCtrl,
  controllerAs: 'vtc',
});
```

And in the parent component template you should specify where to place innards by placing specific tag `<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>`

Checkout the [official](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) documentation and here is a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079587/angularjs-transcluding-multiple-sub-elements-in-a-single-angular-directive) if you have more than one specific element under parent component.